# issues with inheritance and constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance

In defining my Element class I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Dict::Dict()’ word1.cpp:23:
    note: candidates are: Dict::Dict(std::string) word1.cpp:10:
    note: Dict::Dict(const Dict&)
```

I'm not calling anything, I'm merely letting Element inherit from Dict. What's the problem here?

The other error is in my Word class constructor I get the following:

```
In constructor ‘Word::Word(std::string)’: word1.cpp:71:
    note: synthesized method ‘Element::Element()’ first required here
```

I'm really frustrated at this point as everything seems okay to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Dict {
   public:
    string line;
    int wordcount;
    string word;
    vector <string> words;

    Dict(string f) {
        ifstream in(f.c_str());
        if (in) {
            while (in >> word) {
                words.push_back(word);
            }
        }
        else cout << "ERROR couldn't open file" << endl;
        in.close();
    }
};

class Element: public Dict { //Error #1 here 
    //Don't need a constructor
    public:
      virtual void complete(const Dict &d) = 0;
      //virtual void check(const Dict &d) = 0;
      //virtual void show() const = 0;
};

class Word: public Element{
    public:
      string temp;
      Word(string s){ // Error #2 here
          temp = s;
      }
      void complete(const Dict &d){cout << d.words[0];}
};

int main()
{
    Dict mark("test.txt"); //Store words of test.txt into vector
    string str = "blah"; //Going to search str against test.txt
    Word w("blah"); //Default constructor of Word would set temp = "blah"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the constructor taking no arguments for your class `Dict`, if you are defining any constructor for it yourself.

**From where does the no parameter constructor for `Dict` get invoked?**

```
Word w("blah");
```

Creates an `Word` object by calling `Word(string s)`. However, Since `Word` is derived from `Element` which in turn is derived from `Dict`, their default constructors, which take no parameters will be called as well. And you do not have a no parameter constructor defined for `Dict` So the error.

**Solution:**
Either to provide a constructor for class `Dict` which takes no parameters yourself.

```
Dict()
{
}
```

Or
define a constructor in `Element` which calls one of the parameterized constructors of `Dict` in the Member Initializer List.

```
Element():Dict("Dummystring")
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By declaring your own constructor, you're implicitly telling the compiler not to create default constructor. If you want to use `Element` class without passing in anything to `Dict`, you also need to declare your own constructor as well.

You are getting the second error because the compiler was unable to correctly parse `Element` class which is the parent class for `Word`. Again, you'll also have to declare constructor for `Element` as well in order for `Word` class to work.

Comment: It's not just a copy constructor (which he didn't provide). It's providing *any* constructor that prevents the creation of a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors aren't inherited, so you need a constructor for Element. E.g.,

```
Element::Element(string f) : Dict(f) { }
```